# PHP login system security

Tags: php, security, authentication

I'm currently using a PHP login system that checks the user against a database and sets a logged_in cookie. Then when they logout the cookie is removed. I'm not familiar with how easily someone would be able to hack this system, i see a lot of people use cookies as well as sessions. Can someone explain to me like i'm 5 what the significance is of using it that way? In terms of security?

BTW that's all that i use in my login system, is there anything more i should be doing? It's just small websites i'm working with nothing super important.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP login with sessions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18041481/php-login-with-sessions)

Comment: Creating a fake cookie is a one liner in javascript, and there are tons of browser addons for cookie editing, technically your solution is the easiest to 'crack'.

Comment: If that's the case are cookies not recommended at all in a log in system?

Comment: Please add some more details. What are you actually storing in your cookie? Is it a secure token, or just the username? If the latter then a user could just set their cookie in their browser to `user=admin` and take over your system.

Answer (score 1):

We store session on the server and store cookie on the client browsers. It is better if you use session instead of cookie.

Comment: You may want to elaborate to the user what you mean by - "It is better if you use session instead of cookie."